# NullReferenceError for Html.Sitecore().Rendering in Ajax Calls

Tags: presentation, ajax

I need to update page renderings based on search results using ajax call. I have written a method to get rendering collection based on filter and when I call Html.Sitecore().Rendering via loop in view like below:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{450270A9-640A-46B4-80ED-02CCCCCB2549}", new { DataSource = "{C3D52B5F-F236-49DF-A027-6432FE2F80FE}" })
```

I get an error - `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` only for ajax call but above code works for page request.
I researched about this issue and I didn't get any solution.

Is it possible to call Html.Sitecore().Rendering using Ajax

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post the full stack trace of that exception, please.

Comment: @MarkCassidy - Posted stack exception

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution @Html.Sitecore().Rendering() will not work for View rendering type. My rendering was of type View rendering which it was throwing above error.

And also I tried with @Html.Sitecore().ViewRendering() for view rendering type, it dint work as expected.

So I decided to use Controller rendering to make it work.